# Chatting on LAN using Command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, chat

Is there a way to chat between two computers on same LAN using the command prompt in windows, If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few commands built into Windows, but they aren't exactly ... convenient. Also, only *sending* messages is through command-line; received ones are displayed as annoying popups.

---

**`net send`** exists in all versions *up to* XP but is removed in Vista and 7. It uses NetBIOS.

```
net send <targetname> <text>
```

`<targetname>` can be either a user name or a computer.

```
net send tim Hi!
```

To *receive* messages you need to start the Messenger service.

```
sc config Messenger start= demand      (or auto)
sc start Messenger
```

---

**`msg`** exists in XP Pro, and probably all Windows versions with Terminal Services.

```
msg /server <hostname> <targetname> <text>
```

Here `<hostname>` is the computer's name, `<targetname>` can be the receiving user's Windows username (but can be a `*` or a session name or session ID from `qwinsta /server <hostname>`), and `<text>` is obvious.

```
msg /server tims-pc tim Hi!
```

`msg` uses Terminal Services RPC and requires authentication. If you can receive an "Access Denied" message, run this on the remote computer:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v AllowRemoteRPC /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: So, we can't use any commands in windows 7 to send message via command prompt in LAN?

Comment: @Anish: Try `msg`